how to add the tonkeeper wallet to the nextjs app with input switch?
everyone.
Now I'm connecting the ton keeper wallet to my Next.js app.
There is TonkeeperButton for the ton keeper wallet. But this is a button not switch. In my figma design, we should use the switch instead the button. I hope the help from stack overflow developer community.
tonConnectUI from @tonconnect/ui for the customizing button CSS.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
